# How to copy files in node.js / electron efficiently?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am copying a list of files from one place to another using electron and **fs.copyFileSync** (in a loop). In order to not block the whole UI, I am doing it in an invisible window running a worker.js. The main application sends the list of files I want to have copied to the worker via an IPC bus.

Now I got reports from users, saying that during the copying operation the worker is not able to handle any other IPC requests (from other parts of the main app).

So I wondered if the copying operation could be somehow delegated to the OS.
Is maybe fs.copyFile less draining for the nodejs process than fs.copyFileSync?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `fs.promises.copyFile()` (the asynchronous version) which is entirely non-blocking?  You shouldn't even need a worker thread for that.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readFileSync` still blocks the main (or browser) thread where the electron application runs. You can take a look into the 'fs/promises' api and use something like:

```js
import { copyFile } from 'fs/promises';

await Promise.all([copyFile("source-a", "dest-a"), copyFile("source-b", "dest-b"), ...]);
```

so the thread won't block completely. By making these calls async you allow the event loop to continue with other operations and not block it until all operations are done.

Comment: Thanks! I know the APIs and also I know about Promises, that's not the issue.  I am more interested in the theory of async / sync. Do you have some documentation on "By making these calls async you allow the event loop to continue with other operations and not block it until all operations are done."?
AFAIK nodejs is single threaded, so if the files are really copied by nodejs (and not the OS), does using a different API really change the performance?

Comment: @stoefln - Yeah, it makes a huge difference.  Using a synchronous API blocks the event loop during the ENTIRE operation, whereas an asynchronous API only blocks the event loop for a moment while a specific internal file API is called.  Once the internal asynchronous API is called, the actual file operation is handed over to a separate thread in the thread pool and the event loop is completely open to process other events.

Comment: Files can only be copied by the os and every language (even C) asks the os to do something on the filesystem (by using syscalls, pretty interesting topic). However, the way how the os is called is different from language to language and some languages implement different ways to call the os.

By using the ...Sync methods, the event loop will be blocked until the operation is done (see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#synchronous-api). While when using async operations, the event loop won't be blocked and can continue until it receives a signal from the os that the io operation is done.